# Javafx no muestra mi gridpane con imagenes

Tags: java, imagen, eclipse, arraylist, javafx

Quiero que me muestre todas las **imagenes** en un **grid pane** 
pero no me muestra nada y me da error.
Tengo otra clase que devuelve un Arraylist de ImageView con las imagenes cargadas
Las imagenes las tengo el la carpeta root del proyecto y se llaman igual.
He intentado modificar el codigo varias veces pero sin ningún resultado, desde el bucle for no me funciona.
Si quito desde la "prueba" para ver si funcionaba el png que por cierto no funciona hasta el p.setCenter  y lo pongo en comentario todo funciona perfectamente, asi que deduzco que será al añadir imagenes al gridpane

```
package application;

import java.util.Collections;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

public class Main extends Application {
  @Override 
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
      int c = 0;
       Label text = new Label("Memoriza");
       HBox hb = new HBox(text);
       BorderPane p = new BorderPane();
       p.setTop(hb);
       GridPane gp = new GridPane();
       gp.setHgap(5);
       gp.setVgap(5);
       Image prueba = new Image("png1");
       Png img = new Png();

        for(int i = 0; i < 4;i++) {
            for(int f = 0; f < 2;f++) {
                gp.add(img.mazo().get(i),i,f);
            }
        }
               p.setCenter(gp);






    // Create a scene and place it in the stage
    Scene scene = new Scene(p);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Memoriza"); // Set the stage title
    primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
    primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage
  }



  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1118)
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:620)
    at application.Main.start(Main.java:27)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:186)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1110)
    ... 11 more
Exception running application application.Main
```

Edición:
Esta es la clase de PNG
[image: pngclase]

He introducido los png en todas las carpetas/subcarpetas y nada
[image: He introducido los png en todas las carpetas/subcarpetas y nada]

Comment: El problema está en que efectivamente no encuentra el archivo de la imagen. Te recomiendo que agregues una captura de la estructura de directorios de tu proyecto.

Comment: He intentado poner una ruta absoluta y tampoco me funciona

Answer (score 0):

Yo tuve el mismo problema, lo solucione poniendo las imágenes en el mismo paquete que la clase y poniendo la ruta a partir del paquete. O sea debería ser
`Image png1 = new Image("\paqute\png1.png")`